# Which is correct, "highly-populated" or "most populous"?

Tags: phrases

For example, Shanghai is a "highly-populated city " or "one of most populous cities"in China. Are they both correct? If so, which one is more common?

Comment: Google Ngrams aren't a final proof, but [this one](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=highly-populated%2Cmost+populous&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chighly%20-%20populated%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmost%20populous%3B%2Cc0) is in favour of 'most populous'. Although, 'most' is a superlative, and I'm not sure that those two phrases mean exactly the same thing.

Comment: They mean different things. If you consider a city's population to be high (or maybe dense), then it is highly-populated. If it is literally a city with one of the highest populations in the region in question, then it is one of the most populous cities. For example, I don't think anyone would call the city of [Juneau](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Juneau,_Alaska) "highly populated". It is, however, "[one of the most populous cities in Alaska](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_cities_and_census-designated_places_in_Alaska)".

Comment: True. Mumbai could be highly populated city, but Shanghai is the most populous. 'high' and 'the most'... as Lucky says are different.

Comment: by the way, "highly populated city" does not have a hyphen.  Adverb used to modify adjective does not require hyphen.

Comment: In case someone is wondering, "most populous" seems more correct than "most populated": https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/most-populated-or-populous.3370145/

Answer (score 1):

This is just like *many* and *most*.

Definition of *many* by Google:

> a large number of.

Definition of *most* by Google:

> greatest in amount or degree.

---

Hence,

*"highly-populated city"* means a city that is populous while *"most populous city"* means the city is more populated than any other cities.

The difference is that *most* is **a superlative** while *highly populated* is **like a normal adjective**.

Here are few more examples:

> I have many games.
>
> I have the most games *in the world*.